# How to remove entries in a data drame that are dissimilar

Tags: r, dataframe, grepl

I have many rosters of people with statistics that I made into a data.frame `teamroster`.  Only problem is, some people have duplicate names, and don't belong on a roster (because they have a different team name.  Look at case `Matt Duffy` in `teamroster` below).  I want to systematically remove all names and entries that do not have the same team name on the roster.

Here is my raw `data.frame`:

```
teamroster

      Name      Team   G  PA
1  Denard Span Giants 30 135
2    Joe Panik Giants 25 107
3   Matt Duffy Giants 31 127
4   Matt Duffy Astros  3   3
5 Buster Posey Giants 27 108
```

The solution code will recognize that `Matt Duffy` is on a different team, as seen by the `Team` column, and remove him because he is on `Team = Astros`. This is what I want the resulting data frame to look like:

```
finishedteamroster

      Name      Team   G  PA
1  Denard Span Giants 30 135
2    Joe Panik Giants 25 107
3   Matt Duffy Giants 31 127
4 Buster Posey Giants 27 108
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could tabulate the team names then take the maximum of the tabulation.  Note that I used `which.max()` for its side-effect of keeping the table names.

```
idx <- with(df, Team == names(which.max(table(Team))))
df[idx, ]
#           Name   Team  G  PA
# 1  Denard Span Giants 30 135
# 2    Joe Panik Giants 25 107
# 3   Matt Duffy Giants 31 127
# 5 Buster Posey Giants 27 108
```

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(Name = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("Buster Posey", 
"Denard Span", "Joe Panik", "Matt Duffy"), class = "factor"), 
    Team = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Astros", 
    "Giants"), class = "factor"), G = c(30L, 25L, 31L, 3L, 27L
    ), PA = c(135L, 107L, 127L, 3L, 108L)), .Names = c("Name", 
"Team", "G", "PA"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"))
```